# Java - Going through arraylist and outputting highest to lowest numbers?

Tags: java

Is there a way to make it so I can sort through an ArrayList output the highest number found along with the lowest number found?  The way I have it now is a "shoppinglist" which is set up like this:

```
public void addToBag(String anyItem, int anyUnits, double anyCost){
    int checkUnits = anyUnits;
    double checkCost = anyCost;
    if(checkUnits < 0 || checkCost < 0){
        System.out.println("You must enter a value equal to or greater than 0!");
    }else{
    shoppingBag.add(new Item(anyItem, anyUnits, anyCost));
}
}
```

and the output which only outputs the list

```
  public void calculateSalesReceipt(){
    System.out.println("Enter the sales tax percentage (ex. 0.08 for 8%) or type \"random\" for a random number: ");
    double tax = keybd.nextDouble();
    if(tax < 0){
        System.out.println("You must enter a value equal to or greater than 0!");
    }else{
    getPricePreTax();
    total = total;
    taxCost = total * tax;
    finaltotal = total + taxCost;
    System.out.println("Sales Receipt");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    for(Item currentProduct : shoppingBag){
        System.out.println(currentProduct.getName() + " - " + currentProduct.getUnits() + " units " + " - $" + currentProduct.getCost());
    }
    System.out.println("Total cost: $" + total);
    System.out.println("Total tax: $" + taxCost);
    System.out.println("Total cost with tax: $" + finaltotal);
    System.out.println("Do you have any coupons? Enter \"yes\" or \"no\"");
    String answer = keybd.next();
    if(answer.equals("yes")){
                applyCoupon();
            }else if(answer.equals("no")){
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }else if(answer != "yes" || answer != "no"){
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }
    System.out.println("Coupon discounts: $" + couponAmount);
    System.out.println("Grand total: $" + (finaltotal-couponAmount));
}
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

**Would this work?**

```
 public void getLargest(){
    for(Item currentProduct : shoppingBag){
        System.out.println(Collections.max());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want [`Collections.max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) (and `Collections.min()`, respectively).  If you want the entire list in order, you probably want `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: public void getLargest(){
        for(Item currentProduct : shoppingBag){
            System.out.println(Collections.max());
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Function<Item, Double> itemCostFunction = new Function<Item, Double>() {
  @Override public Double apply(Item item) {
    return item.getCost();
  }
};

List<Item> sortedItems = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(itemCostFunction).sortedCopy(shoppingBag);
```

Now

```
Item biggest = Iterables.getLast(sortedItems);  // costliest
Item smallest = sortedItems.get(0);  // cheapest
```

Comment: ...yes, thas really nice. But maybe as the guy is learning, its better to understand how to do it using the standard api. The last line looks a bit like magic... :-)

Comment: Why not use ordering.max / ordering.min?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to sort on? Cost?

You can create an new class; `CostComparator` implementing a `Comparator<Item>`, and compare `Item`s depeding on their price.